# Error: Cannot read properties of null using the Hedera Token Service with JS SDK

Tags: javascript, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

In `TokenMintTransaction` and `TokenBurnTransaction` when I convert into bytes using .toBytes() and build a transaction from bytes using Transaction.fromBytes() I am getting this error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token' )

Answer (score 1):

This same issue was found here,

https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/issues/447.

The issue is resolved by upgrading the SDK version from 2.0.15 to 2.0.25